# Having issues integrating Scandit SDK into my app

Tags: android, scandit

Decided to use Scandit SDK to get the barcode scanning feature in my app. Unfortunately, since I'm relatively new to Android development and Java in general I've run into a few issues that I can't seem to work out. The demo that Scandit provided doesn't give any errors(runs fine) but crashes when I try to start it up (pressing a button from one activity is meant to start it up). I've tried reading the logcat and googling a solution to the problems but I'm not getting the right solutions. Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Logcat is provided below:

```
 10-08 23:30:00.807  21563-21563/com.kwesimbia.management D/AndroidRuntime? Shutting down VM
 10-08 23:30:00.807  21563-21563/com.kwesimbia.management W/dalvikvm? threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa4228)
 10-08 23:30:00.817  21563-21563/com.kwesimbia.management E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL   EXCEPTION: main

 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3082)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3077)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)                 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kwesimbia.management.ScanditSDKDemoSimple
 at com.kwesimbia.management.Activity_D.initiateCodeScan(Activity_D.java:63)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3077)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

 10-08 23:30:00.817    32726-587/? E/EmbeddedLogger? App crashed! 
 Process: com.kwesimbia.management
 10-08 23:30:00.817    32726-587/? E/EmbeddedLogger? App crashed! 
 Package: com.kwesimbia.management v1 (1.0)

 10-08 23:30:00.817    32726-587/? E/EmbeddedLogger? 
 Application Label: firstapp
 10-08 23:30:00.827    32726-587/? W/ActivityManager? 
 Force finishing activity com.kwesimbia.management/.Activity_D
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem as well, my solution was to extract the library files and put them as their files in the lib folder

The library basically isn't being exported with it

**EDIT**

So I checked out my project, basically I did these things:

In the `libs` folder I have a new folder called `armeabi` and inside that I have `libscanditsdk-android-3.3.1.so`

Then in my build path I have also referenced the jar file that they provide:

`<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/GIT/Android/FwayScannerProject/FwayScanner/libs/scanditsdk-barcodepicker-android-3.3.1.jar"/>`

Comment: Will just look for the full solution, hold up.

Comment: Ahh okay. I did mine with eclipse. The problem is with  the application not seeing the library.